# Configure Poco to have raw characters

Tags: c++, poco, poco-libraries

I want to ask if it is possible to configure the SAX Poco parser so that it returns the original characters of the xml file.
In fact, when i have in the xlm file & lt; to encode < i have as a result of the SAX parser <  while i want to have the original encoded characters as it is & lt; How do i avoid this decoding happening form SAX parser.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you mean by "raw" characters? Give us an example. Maybe show some code of something you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for your response, in fact when i have in the xlm file :                                  <f_libelle> a &lt; b </f_libelle>  where &lt; is encoded for <  i have as a result of the poco parser  <f_libelle> a < b </f_libelle> while i have to find the same characters as the input xml, i want to have <f_libelle> a &lt; b </f_libelle>, can you please help me.

Comment: i mean by raw characters, the input characters in the xml file

Comment: it's using the SAX (Simple API for XML) in the implementation of the method  void characters (XMLChar ch [] const, int start, int length) of the ContentHandler interface

Comment: Details like this should be in the question itself. [Edit] the question and explain what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks @jdv, it's done ;)

Comment: Thanks. Ok, so you want to parse some XML but keep the raw HTML entities without decoding them to their rendered characters. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1777878/1531971

Comment: yes, it is exactly what i want to do with C++ langage and SAX parser

Comment: You probably need to look at https://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.XML.XMLReader.html and where it sets/gets the "EntityResolver". There are some hints about that around the web.

Comment: Thanks very much jdv